# Connecting to remote golang server

Tags: go

I've been trying for what feels like days to remotely connect to a sockjs-go (https://github.com/igm/sockjs-go) server application I've written.  I'm developing locally on Windows, and everything works fine.  When I try running on a remote linux server (after building on the linux box, obviously), I am never able to connect to the sockjs server.

- I've tried running the example echoserver web example from the sockjs-go repository on the remote machine, and I cannot connect to it either.
- I made sure to change the sockjs client IP from my local machine to the remote machine.
- I have the right public IP address and can view a static web page served by lighttpd.

I've tried searching on google for anything golang-specific, but have found nothing.  Any suggestions would be great.

**update**

I am using the echo test code verbatim given here:  https://github.com/igm/sockjs-go/tree/v2/examples/webecho

As far as I can tell, the linux server isn't filtering.  Port 8080 is closed before running webecho, and is open after starting webecho.

I have also tried https://coderwall.com/p/wohavg/creating-a-simple-tcp-server-in-go , which I can connect to locally but not remotely.  Any ideas why I cannot connect to go programs remotely, but other programs have no problems connecting?

Comment: Post some code + errors (if any) + connection log output (i.e. from lighttpd, if you're proxying through it)

Comment: Is the remote linux machine filtering? Is there some other firewall in between?

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently using ports that weren't supported.  I ended up running as root (sudo) and binding to port 80, since I knew it was serving http traffic appropriately.